# Group/Aggregate data.table columns by a ref from another data.table file.

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to aggregate columns of a following data:

```
       Label    A  B   C  D E
  1:     a    0.00 0 0.00 0 1
  2:     b    0.00 0 0.00 0 2
  3:     c    0.00 0 0.00 0 3
  4:     d    0.00 0 0.11 0 4
  5:     e    0.44 0 4.00 0 5
```

into two groups by the following ref data;

```
ID Exp
1:  A Dis
2:  B Con
3:  C Con
4:  D Con
5:  E Dis
```

So a desired column output is;

```
Label    A E  B C D
```

Any help or pointers to accomplish this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `order` based on the 'Exp' column, extract the 'ID' and use that reorder the dataset

```
dt[, c("Label", refdt[order(-Exp)]$ID), with = FALSE]
```

---

Or with `setcolorder`

```
setcolorder(dt, c("Label", refdt[order(-Exp)]$ID))
dt
#   Label    A E B    C D
#1:     a 0.00 1 0 0.00 0
#2:     b 0.00 2 0 0.00 0
#3:     c 0.00 3 0 0.00 0
#4:     d 0.00 4 0 0.11 0
#5:     e 0.44 5 0 4.00 0
```

As @Frank mentioned, it is better to extract the column from inside the `[]`

```
setcolorder(dt, c("Label", refdt[order(-Exp), ID]))
```

NOTE: Assuming both the datasets are `data.table`

Comment: `DT[i]$col` is less efficient than `DT[i, col]`.